# the_post_thumbnail("size") returns same image for all sizes except thumbnail

Tags: media-library, post-thumbnails

I've got 3 default image sizes set up in "Setting > Media Settings > Image Sizes"

However, when I use anything but "thumbnail" as the image size parameter in the_post_thumbnail(), it returns the full size image.

Am I doing something wrong or could there be an active filter making this happen?

For example, this *should* return the medium 300x300px max size image:

```
echo the_post_thumbnail("medium");
```

And this should return the "large" 1024x1024px max:

```
echo the_post_thumbnail("large");
```

Comment: Do the sizes in question actually exist for the uploaded file? WordPress creates the resized images at the time of the upload, and if the sizes were not set when the file was uploaded, then the resized images would not have been created, and so trying to get those various sizes won't work.

Comment: Yes, I have several variations of this image inside the uploads folder. I deleted the image and reuploaded just to be sure they were being created.

Comment: Can you edit the question with your theme's `add_image_size()` code added?